# Ruby on Rails Actions help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have my index page which posts a single entry instead of the usual scaffold default of all of the entries. I told it to link to an action and it just responds to "Couldn't find Post with ID=all". It is the same as the default index method and index view. I assume this has something to do with routing but being no I have no clue. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you posted the code for the action (and view) in question.

Comment: I JUST got it working after fiddling a bit. I added map.connect '/posts/all/', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'all' before map.resources :posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "all" name is misleading. If you want a page to display all the posts then the index page is perfect for that. If you want to show a subset of the posts then I recommend adding another action to your controller with a better name and then this to the routes.rb file:

```
map.resources :posts, :collection => { :some => :get }
```

Which you then can reference by using `some_posts_path` or `some_posts_url`.

For more information read the [Official Ruby on Rails Routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).